# How to solve the map direction is not showing in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-maps

When I enter location 
**it is not showing route for (Starting point and ending point) :**

[image: Screenshot]

**These are the logs:**

```
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.lang.Object, long, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.lang.Object, long, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.lang.Object, long, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.lang.Object, long, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.net.InetAddress[] libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(java.lang.String, android.system.StructAddrinfo, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.net.InetAddress[] libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(java.lang.String, android.system.StructAddrinfo, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.net.InetAddress[] libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(java.lang.String, android.system.StructAddrinfo, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void libcore.io.Linux.connect(java.io.FileDescriptor, java.net.InetAddress, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void libcore.io.Linux.connect(java.io.FileDescriptor, java.net.InetAddress, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.net.InetAddress[] libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(java.lang.String, android.system.StructAddrinfo, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void libcore.io.Linux.connect(java.io.FileDescriptor, java.net.InetAddress, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void libcore.io.Linux.connect(java.io.FileDescriptor, java.net.InetAddress, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.net.InetAddress[] libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(java.lang.String, android.system.StructAddrinfo, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.net.InetAddress[] libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(java.lang.String, android.system.StructAddrinfo, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.net.InetAddress[] libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(java.lang.String, android.system.StructAddrinfo, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.net.InetAddress[] libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(java.lang.String, android.system.StructAddrinfo, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.lang.Object, long, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.lang.Object, long, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.lang.Object, long, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.lang.Object, long, int)
W/zygote64: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.lang.Object, long, int)
I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=0B, data=120KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=0B, data=0B
```

Comment: these are not your error logs, you posted info logs.  Please provide proper "error log" details.

Answer (score 0):

For us to help you better, you need to provide details on what you have tried so far or the code which didn't work.

In general, if you need to open a map, which shows directions from point A to point B, here is a code that works.

```
 Uri.Builder directionsBuilder = new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme("https")
                .authority("www.google.com")
                .appendPath("maps")
                .appendPath("dir")
                .appendPath("")
                .appendQueryParameter("api", "1")
                .appendQueryParameter("destination", latitude + "," + longitude);

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, directionsBuilder.build()));
```